# What does the myObj.param?.otherParam operator do and how is it used?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was reading the fundamentals guide for React Navigation and in the section for [passing parameters to routes](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params#passing-params-to-a-previous-screen) I came across this bit of code that I've never seen before.

```
if (route.params?.post) {      
  // Do something
}
```

I've never seen the `?` operator used that way, I've only used the ternary operator.  When searching the only other thing I found is the nullish assignment operator `??=`.

I fiddled with it in the console and it seems to check if `param` exists so that if it doesn't exist it doesn't error when asking for `.post`

My first thought was that is a ternary operator without the second argument, but the third argument appears to be required.

So my question is, in the above code block, what is the `?` doing, what is that called, and how/when is it used?
Thanks

Comment: It's called [`Optional Chaining`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: This is called optional chaining and in short terms is a way to prevent having to write 1000's of null checks - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). You can use it to check if the preceding variable is null, so that you could spare yourself checking for null/undefined properties.

```js
// want to access blub.test.smth
if(blub && blub.test) {
  // possibly access blub.test.smth
  const value = blub.test.smth;
}
```

vs

```js
const value = blub?.test?.smth
```

Comment: Thanks! That does make it a lot simpler.